# My CSS grid < grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(0.7rem, 2rem, 4rem) ) !important; > isn't working!! (For responsiveness.)

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, vite

I was watching this video by [Web Dev Simplified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUD1AWZVgQ8&t=660s) by YT (At 12:20 in the video), I was already using grid in my project, and tried to implement auto-fit but didn't work!!
I tried implementing it but all my skill icons go into a single column in the center of the skill section!!
[Github link](https://github.com/mjshubham21/Mjshubham21Portfolio.git)

```
//My skill.jsx:

import React from "react";

function Skills() {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="skills">
        <div data-aos="zoom-out-down" className="card">
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/assets/html5.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">HTML</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/assets/github.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">GitHub</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/assets/node.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">NodeJs</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/assets/password.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">Authentication</p>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <img className="skillIcon" src="/assets/api.svg" alt="Icon" />
            <p className="skillName">API</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skills;

//My CSS for it:

.skills {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 1.8rem;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 7s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    auto-fit,
    minmax(0.7rem, 2rem, 4rem)
  ) !important;
}
.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
}

.skillIcon,
.skillName {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

I wanna implement the:
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(0.7rem, 2rem, 4rem));

Comment: I just tried using minmax clamp(0.7rem, 2rem, 4rem) but didn't work.

Comment: what you are trying is invalid. If you are watching a tutorial that is suggesting such value then stop watching it right now

Comment: also the value doesn't make any sense if you think about it. You are comparing 3 constants so not sure what kind of result you want

Comment: It's not actually invalid... clamp is an actual function in CSS, here's a link : [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) clamp has 3 constants because it stands for (min, default, max) min and max are the limits based on viewport size, clamp makes sure the element stays within these limits...

Comment: Hi, if all the parameters in clamp are constants what is the point? The chosen value will never change, in your example 2rem is always greater than 0.7rem and always less than 4rem. If you look at the examples in the site you reference you’ll see that there is always something in each of them that is not a fixed constant.

Comment: The element size varies depending on the base font of the page, and the size of the viewport... Among the 3 constants, only 1 is ever implemented based on display size... 1st and 3rd are the upper and lower limits.

Comment: I tried clamp with font size on the body tag and it worked as expected... but I'm facing an error with the grid!!